# How can I make Safari cmd+number shortcut switch tabs instead of opening the bookmark associated with that number?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

I'm used to switching tabs with cmd+x where x is a number and takes me to tab x in firefox and pretty much every other browser I've ever used.
I like safari's speed and would like to try it a bit, but the cmd+x shortcut is burned in my brain and every time I use safari I end up screwing up.
I'd like to know if its possible to change this behavior, because this simple thing is a stopper for me.

Comment: In addition, the current (6.0.3) behaviour of replacing whatever one had on the browser window is highly annoying. I often press cmd-1/2/3 in accident (i.e. while taking screen shots using shift-cmd-3/4). These keys REALLY should be reassigned by Apple. Bad feature. (I'm not the only one: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3464021?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: One more thing: the fact that "Show Previous Tab" and "Show Next Tab" are present in the Safari menu means that you can assign _any_ shortcuts for changing tabs in System Preferences (Keyboard->Shortcuts)

Comment: I'm putting a bounty on [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201259/5472) how to do this with Safari v9

Comment: As of OS X El Capitan, this feature is now enabled by default in Safari.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check [SafariTabSwitching](https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching).

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Safari 5.1.2/Lion.

Comment: Works for Safari 6.0.3/Mountain Lion :D

Comment: Works great in Safari 7/Mavericks too.

Comment: Updated for Safari 8 (10538.35.8) / Yosemite (10.10, 14A238x) too.

Answer (score 30):

In case you are coming from Chrome and want to use

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[0-9]</kbd> for switching tabs (instead of cycling through your preset top sites) take a look at:

[github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching](https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching)

> Safari Tab Switching is a Safari SIMBL plugin which allow switching between tabs using Cmd+1-9.

**Update:**

Safari Version 9.0.2 (El Capitan) has native support for this:

[image]

Comment: This is much nicer than Ctrl+Tab!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I just updated to Yosemite and I was hoping to replace Chrome with Safari and cmd + 0-9 was one of the shortcuts I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me. I run safari 8.0.4 and Even though installation was successful, the `cmd` + `[0-9]` shortcut does not work

Comment: @gprasant I'm running Version 8.0.4 too. Perhaps have a look at the issue tracker on github?

Comment: UPDATE: Looking at this issue - https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching/issues/27 - helped me fix the problem. It now works for me on Safari 8.0.4

Answer (score 26):

Easy!

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: It seems you have answered your own question. That's a good way to share your knowledge, as said in Stack Exchange FAQs.

Answer (score 11):

In El Capitan, OSX 10.11, this has been included as a new feature of Safari Version 9.0 (11601.1.50).

Go to Preferences > Tabs > Use ⌘-1 through ⌘-9 to switch tabs

Comment: OMG! FINALLY! HAVE ALL THE UPVOTES!

Comment: Why was this awarded 50 points?

Comment: Yeah, why not A MILLION?!!

Comment: Now I wish Finder tab can use the same shortcut!

Answer (score 9):

In most native OS X applications, the key presses <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> will cycle left and right through tabs, respectively. Safari understands these.

If you use something like [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net), then you can assign gestures (such as a three-finger swipe left or right) to these key presses, and get tab cycling across most of OS X.

Comment: I go with these because they stack nicely with history.back and history.forward (Cmd-[ and Cmd-] respectively). Cursor keys often get stuck on input fields when attempting to navigate history.

Answer (score 4):

- To go to the previous tab, press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>← Left</kbd>
- To go to the next tab, press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>→ Right</kbd>

*Traveller’s note :* These keyboards equivalents may be reversed in a right-to-left environment.

Answer (score 4):

To go to the next tab 
<kbd>⎇ Control</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or

 <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or 
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>→ Right</kbd>

To go to the previous tab 
<kbd>⎇ Control</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or 
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or 
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>← Left</kbd>

Comment: this answer is the most complete

Comment: That's what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Safari 9.0, released today for 10.9 Mavericks and 10.10 Yosemite, along side with the 10.11 El Capitan release, has introduced this natively.

[image]

There are two options. If checked, ⌘-1 through ⌘-9 will switch to tab 1 through 9, respectfully. This will change the original behavior of mapping to the favorites bar bookmark 1 through 9. Those will be changed to Command-Option-1 through Command-Option-9.

**If unchecked, while it does not say it**, the behavior is reversed. Command-Number will still be the favorites bar bookmark, while Command-Option-Number will be the tab. This flipping of behavior matches the Command-Click and Command-Option click behavior for opening a link.

It's undocumented.

Comment: Good catch. This should be upvoted more!

Answer (score 2):

What about setting bookmarks 0-9 to be bookmarklets that change window tabs?

Comment: Looks like my only option, so far... I'll try that.

Comment: how can this be done?

Comment: @yanis - if there's something specific you want to know, your best bet is to open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the keyboard shortcut used in Chrome and Opera: Option+Cmd+(left/right arrow keys). This can be assigned in System Preferences-->Keyboard-->Shortcuts-->App Shortcuts. Press the plus button and add a pair for Safari with the command names "Show [Previous/Next] Tab" and then type the key sequences you want to use. Pretty handy. Good luck!

Comment: I also wanted to have chrome like shortcut but wasn't able to find the right command name for the shortcut. How did you find out the command? Is there a list provided by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>
the simplest way

Answer (score -3):

Yes ctrl + (0-9) by using this shortcut you can navigate across multiple tabs in windows

Comment: Could you explain how control + 0 is different than command + 0 ?

Comment: By "in windows" venu means "in Windows" -- It is, in this context, an entirely pointless and unhelpful suggestion. Ctrl for Windows, Cmd for OSX.

Comment: This suggestion is incorrect on OS X. Control-digits do nothing in Safari, and Command-digits open items in the Favorites bar.